# For which $x \in \mathbb{R}$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

One problem of my exercise book asks for which $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the following series converges:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

The answer given by the exercise book is $|x|\leq 1$, but from the theory (*Taylor's theorem*) I know that this series converges to $(e^x-1)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

So what? Could you clarify the situation?

Comment: It certainly does converge for $x\in [-1,1]$... however it also converges for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus [-1,1]$ :P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.** The ratio test: you have, as $n \to +\infty$,
$$
\left|\frac{u_{n+1}(x)}{u_n(x)}\right|=\left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\times\frac{n!}{x^n}\right|=\frac{|x|}{n+1} \to 0.
$$ Thus **the radius of convergence is infinite**.

Comment: The first part of your answer (*D'Alembert's ratio criterion*) is clear. But could you please explain that in more details the conclusions? I'm not familiar with the concept of radius of convergence (the definition was not given in my course).

Comment: @user62029 Please have a look at the ratio test here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Comment: Thanks. So basically there's a typo in the book, right?

Comment: Yes, there is a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This series equals $e^x - 1$ and yes, it does converge for all real $x$.